# How to create all fragments when application start

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating number of fragments programmatically. All of them have different layouts and active fragment's layout is changed after swapping between fragments.

When program is started `FragmentPagerAdapter` creates first two fragment. If I select last fragment (for example first one to seventh one) `FragmentPagerAdapter` starts to create seventh fargment and then sixth fragment. At this point I want to select the current fragment using code below.

```
`(FragmentMasaDesign) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get
                                (myViewPager.getCurrentItem());`
```

`myViewPager.getCurrentItem()` returns 6. That is true because I have select 7th fragment and its index is 6. However I have only four fragments that are created these are 1st-2nd-6th-7th. Thus `getFragments()` method returns me these four fargments and it can't select the current active fragment because of the value that is returned by `myViewPager.getCurrentItem()`

Is there any way to create all fragments at start of the appliction or how can I get the current fragment before other fragments created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the number of fragments on the viewpager with [offscreenpagelimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29).

```
viewpager.offscreenpagelimit(6);
```

Comment: This should be the best way!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ArrayList<Departman> lstDepartmanlar;
    public ArrayList<MasaDizayn> lstMasaDizayn;
    ArrayList<String> masaIsimleri;
    public String[] masaPlanIsmi;
    Fragment fragment;
    public Fragment[] fragments = null;

    public static FragmentMasaDesign newInstance(ArrayList<String> masalar, String DepartmanAdi) {
        FragmentMasaDesign myFragment = new FragmentMasaDesign();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArrayList("masalar", masalar);
        args.putString("departmanAdi", DepartmanAdi);
        myFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myFragment;
    }

    public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        fragment = null;
        if (fragments == null)
            fragments = new Fragment[lstDepartmanlar.size()];
        for (int j = 0; j < lstDepartmanlar.size(); j++) {
            if (i == j) {
                for (Departman departman : lstDepartmanlar) {
                    if (departman.DepartmanEkrani.contentEquals(masaPlanIsmi[i])) {
                        masaIsimleri = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (MasaDizayn masaDizayn : lstMasaDizayn) {
                            if (masaDizayn.MasaPlanAdi.contentEquals(departman.DepartmanEkrani)) {
                                masaIsimleri.add(masaDizayn.MasaAdi);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                fragment = newInstance(masaIsimleri, lstDepartmanlar.get(i).DepartmanAdi);
            }
        }
        fragments[i] = fragment;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstDepartmanlar.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "OBJECT " + (position + 1);
    }
}
```

I have created a public fragment array and then stored the created fragment in this array then I have called the current fragment from this array like:

```
   public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        fragment = collectionPagerAdapter.fragments[mViewPager.getCurrentItem()];
    }
```

Also it is possible to find the visible fragment on screen. I will share its code later.

Thanks to all who spend time for my quesntion.

Answer (score 0):

You could do replace one fragment by another fragment like the following

```
DiplayFragment newFragment = new DiplayFragment();

                                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                            .beginTransaction();
                                    transaction
                                            .replace(R.id.nav_fl_frag_container, newFragment);
                                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                                    transaction.commit();
```